# Sending data to a different server securely in PHP

Tags: security, post, encryption

I am looking into ways of sending highly sensitive, varying, encrypted data from one server to another, preferably using php. I do not own the servers, and they will initially have shared hosting.

I know "post" can be secure, but my concern really is more on the receiving end - how do I prevent attacks from hackers from posting to the same server with random data and tell if the data received is genuine? I could probably create and send a random salt (based on the date, for example) but what if a hacker tried this?

Comment: What you want is to authenticate the client and authorize the action that is supposed to be performed on the server. There is a million different ways of doing this like requiring and API key and only permit the associated action after you verified that the API key is indeed correct. This solves your immediate problem of providing integrity to the stored data. This is only the first step of hindering "hackers" of doing anything with your data, because you have to take the whole system into account when performing threat modelling.

Comment: Thanks. Having never used API keys, is this something I can create myself, or do I have to use a third party such as Google?  If I can create my own, are there any tutorials? A search just brings up Google API and a couple of other companies. NB, I know PHP quite well, but not really any other languages.